# SQL server generate huge amout of data to pdf file

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf, pdf-generation

I am creating a system that will generate PDF letter, but my problem is one of my table has 10000+ data and it is taking more than 1 hour to generate the letter, can I ask for a help on how to improve my codes to lighten its process?

here is my current SQL Query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mPDF_gen048] 
@gfromDate VARCHAR(10),
@gtoDate VARCHAR(10) 

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @fromDate DATE
DECLARE @toDate DATE
DECLARE @totaldays INT

SET @fromDate = (
        SELECT convert(VARCHAR(10), @gfromDate, 101)
        )
SET @toDate = (
        SELECT convert(VARCHAR(10), @gtoDate, 101)
        )

SET @totaldays = (
        SELECT datediff(day, @fromdate, @toDate) + 2
        )

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) = ''
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @counter INT = 1

WHILE @counter < @totaldays
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = ((SELECT REPLACE(UPPER(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @fromDate, 106), 8)), ' ', '') AS [Mon-YYYY]))

    SET @tablename = replace(@tablename, ' ', '')

    SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT 
            ccode,
            refdate,
            refcount,
            accname,
            add1,
            add2,
            zip,
            stat,
            statdate,
            stat2,
            statdate2,
            stat3,
            statdate3,
            address,
            courier,
            pupdate,
            esent,
            recvby,
            rel,
            defbranch FROM gen_048_' + @tablename + ' WHERE refdate = ''' + REPLACE(convert(VARCHAR(10), @fromDate), '-','') + ''''

    IF (@counter < @totaldays - 1)
    begin
        set @sql = @sql + ' union '
    end

        SET @fromDate = dateadd(day, 1, @fromDate)
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
END
PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Is the problem with this SP?  Is it taking too long to run?  If so can you include the execution plan from the calling code and table schemas.

Comment: yah it is taking too long to finish, that is the only problem with this SP.

Comment: Without a query plan and table schemas it's hard to tell where your performance can be improved.  One area to look into: UNION can be a expensive operation, as it has to deduplicate each of the queries, before returning the final resultset.  If your tables do not contain duplicates considered UNION ALL instead.  Another area: loops undermine the set based nature of SQL.  If possible best avoided.

Comment: I created a temporary solution for this, I set a menu where the user can declare the quantity they wish to generate, but I have some error, whenever the user select 1000 and submit, it generates 1192 pdf pages instead of 1000 only.